# Operation of a basic SR latch

Tags: digital-logic

[image]
Consider a SR latch. I have a doubt in that. why the outputs of a latch are always complement to each other.
Please clarify this to me,take any input and show that P is complement of Q.
Also in textbook they have given 11 input combination is forbidden,so that shouldn't be applied.
What happens if we really give 11 input,do we get output or don't or what will happen?????

Comment: Your last question is easy to analyze.. what do you think?

Comment: Hack-a-day just posted (yesterday) a blog about this very thing [here](http://hackaday.com/2015/09/23/learn-flip-flops-with-simulation/) and an even more extensive one [here](http://hackaday.com/2015/09/24/learn-flip-flops-with-more-simulation/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand SR latch, you should know the initial output values P and Q. In working of latch we want P and Q to be complement of each other.That's how latch works.

Once we have that in mind see the following truth table for NOR gate
[image]

Now, see the output when A=1 and B=0,1. When one of the input (A=1) of NOR gate is one irrespective of the value of the other input (B=0 or 1), output is going to be zero. This is the reason why both inputs in SR latch can't be 1. Because once both inputs S and R are 1 even though initial values of outputs(P=0,Q=1 or P=1,Q=0) are complement of each other, it will make both outputs P and Q to be equal to 0 which is invalid as functionality of latch. Hence, both S and R as 1 is prohibited.

Once you know the initial output values(P and Q) and two inputs you can find the next output values by following truth table for NOR SR latch

[image]